# Mitsubishi L200 MK4 2003 right back passenger window wont go down

Tags: mitsubishi, power-windows

I have recently got an old Mitsubishi l200 mk4 that I am restoring back to its former glory.

The back right passenger window won't go down. I have taken off the panel and I can see the motor working and the arm going up and down but it appears to not be pulling it down or the window is not dropping as a result of gravity.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you check the regulator cable? Is it damaged?

Comment: I have not, only on the basis I don't know what that is? All I can see is a metal arm with a plastic wheel on the end that the glass rolls along as it descends. well if it worked properly

Comment: You can google the image for power window regulator cable. If this cable is damaged, then the window lifting will not happen despite the moto working

Comment: Did you ever get your issue fixed?

Comment: Yea I did. The window wasn't attached to the motor so nothing pulling it up and down